# Extend backbone for add new custom Rest Api

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, backbone

I would like to know how i can extend the backbone from wordpress to be able to add custom rest api?

I have created a wp-extend-core/v2/themes-generated endpoint, and to be able to use it in admin I would need a javascript call to it.

After reading up on how wordpress default endpoint works I came to the idea of going all backbone for something like this.
This would bring me closer to their coding style.

I created a js file in which I added this code:

```
(function (window, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    wp.api.init({
        versionString: "wp-extend-core/v2/",
        modelEndpoints: false
    });
})(window);
```

I went in to see if it would find their custom endpoints of mine and to my surprise it recognized all of them ( I mean 2 of them )

Now I come with the problem.

When I called the endpoint in my code part, after I get the response ( which is ok ) I get an error in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: p.models[i] is not a constructor
```

Here I have the code that calls my endpoint.

```
            window.wp.api.loadPromise.done(() => {
                // @ts-ignore
                const ThemesGenerated = new window.wp.api.collections.ThemesGenerated();
                ThemesGenerated.fetch({data:{}}).done(themes => console.info(themes));
            });
```

From what the error explains to me in the console, the problem would come from the model that does not exist for that controller.

My question is:

How can I register a pattern to this controller?

As an observation:

They somehow dynamically generate those models after calling /wp-json/wp/v2.
It does this to me too when I call wp.api.init, but it doesn't find my models.

I apologize for my English if I've upset anyone.

**edit:**

It's a new interface.
These endpoints I will use for a plugin to generate code parts for a custom theme.

An example would be exactly the `/wp-json/wp-extend-core/v2/theme-generated` endpoint.
This endpoint should search my existing themes and return only themes created with my plugin.
The endpoint is functional, it returns my data as it should, but I'm having a problem with the backbone model.

I forgot to specify. This wordpress backbone extension I use in combination with react.

I'm thinking that the chosen combination has nothing to do with it, because even when I call it from the console it still gives me the same problem.

Specifically, I chose this to be able to move forward faster with work on the plugin and I noticed that it knows how to do my validations for authentication and other security procedures in admin.

Comment: are you extending an existing WP interface or is this a new interface? Backbone should be considered legacy for most things, it's better and easier to use a more modern framework for brand new user interfaces, especially given the very poor documentation surrounding backbone in WordPress and use of react and modern WordPress JS packages in use

Comment: It's a new interface.

Comment: I saw you replied but instead of editing your question or leaving a comment you accidentally posted it as the solution. I deleted it and edited your Q to add the info. I would strongly advise against using backbone if your goal is to speed up development and save time implementing authentication with the REST API, it is a major mistake! WP already has APIs that do not use backbone but instead follow modern API conventions, that know how to speak with the REST API and authenticate already, e.g. the `@wordpress/api-fetch` package, or the built in library documented in the REST API handbook.

Comment: After talking to you I understand where I went wrong. Thank you very much for your help.
I'll pass on the ```@wordpress/api-fetch```.

I'm sorry for a replay with "As Another Answer".